# What is an alternative for hitting the nail on the head?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

What is a good expression that means you succeeded in your task?

For example, I would like to say that the designers of an exhibition succeeded in their task to make the atmosphere warm and inviting.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thanks! Ideally, I would like a more academic/formal expression.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thanks for your comment, I will update the tags.

Comment: The designers of the exhibit exceeded expectations in making the atmosphere warm and inviting? Outdid themselves in making the atmosphere warm and inviting? Something more like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *exceeded all expectations*, *outdid themselves*, *went (way) above and beyond*, or *were spot on*?

Your example:

> The designers of the exhibition *exceeded all expectations* in making the
> atmosphere warm and inviting.
>
> The designers of the exhibition *outdid themselves* in making the
> atmosphere warm and inviting.
>
> The designers of the exhibition *went (way) above and beyond* in making the
> atmosphere warm and inviting.
>
> The designers of the exhibition *were spot on* in making the
> atmosphere warm and inviting.